# Changing ASP Core default route to different controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I cannnot get my ASP .NET Core MVC site to route to different controller other than Home. I changed the default route in `Startup` (it is the only route):

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=profile}/{action=index}/{id?}");
        });
```

my `ProfileController` looks like:

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("index")]
    public IActionResult Index() 
    {
        return View();
    }
    ...
}
```

But all I get is 404 returned form the Kestrel server on navigating to base URL.

Comment: try with `Profile` and `Index` instead of `profile` and `index`

Comment: no difference..

Comment: Yep...I posted an answer with an working example. The route is note case sensitive, so `Profile` and `profile` is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've just created a new project and it worked for me. Maybe you're doing something else wrong.

Here's what I did.

- Create a new asp.net core web application project (choose MVC template)
- Update the default route in the Startup.cs:

  ```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      app.UseBrowserLink();
    } else {
      app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes => {
      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "default",
          template: "{controller=profile}/{action=index}/{id?}");
    });
  }
  ```
- Create the Profile Controller:

  ```
  public class ProfileController : Controller {
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index() {
      return View();
    }
  }
  ```
- Create the Index View for the Profile Controller:

[image]

- Run the project and the Profile's Index page should open.

UPDATE:

The problem was the `[HttpGet("index")]` in the Profile Controller.

Comment: bugger it was the `HttpGet` attribute ?!

Comment: Yep. If I insert `[HttpGet("index")]` on my method It stop working. I guess HttpGet is for Web API not MVC. If you're building a web api and needs a web page, you can mix API and MVC.

Comment: No I can use HttpGet and HttpPost attribute elsewhere - ineed I prefer them, just the default index gets screwed it seems if you use it.